# What's the difference between "Beware" and "Be careful"?

Tags: differences

I have seen different kinds of notice in Computer games like "BEWARE!!!" and "BE CAREFUL!Watch your step!"

and What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While the denotation of the two terms is very similar, the connotation is often quite different.

*Beware* is always a serious warning about something very dangerous.

> Beware the Ides of March (there are guys out there with knives, and your name is engraved upon all of them)!

*Be careful* is a much more general advisory about exercising caution ranging from the ordinary to the extreme:

> Be careful. Some of the paint may still be wet.
>
> Be careful. The extraterrestrial flesh-eaters have landed and are looking for lunch!